# Difference between using of view model with live data and without live data

Tags: android

What is the difference between using View model with live data and using View Model without live data in android as to save state it is sufficient to use only view model? what is the purpose of using live data?

Answer (score 0):

MVVM(Model-View-ViewModel) is a coding pattern and recently recommended by the developer community at google for Android developers, at Google IO 2018

LiveData is a new Architecture component launched by Google, which is lifecycle aware. Once you start observing the live data object, any changes to that object will be provided in your observer. LiveData is for the ease of use, rest you can put your own login to save the state. There is nothing like, you have to use live data if you want to use MVVM